# Why can't I fight Flowey at the end of a Pacifist Run

Tags: undertale

I recently bought Undertale, and I've had a lot of fun with it. I'm currently going for pacifist.

I got all the way up to the Asgore fight and mercy'd him. In the judgement hall, Sans told me that I did a pacifist run, and my stats and the game files both said that I was level 1 and had 0 exp. Whenever I beat Asgore, I mercy him and then Flowey steals his soul. After the screen flashes, and I'm in a room where Flowey once stood. Nothing there except a door to the next room. The credits go on, I get the phone call, then it sends me back to the menu.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undertale Pacifist Ending](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253175/undertale-pacifist-ending)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this focuses on the endgame stuff, while that focuses on post game stuff.

Comment: If you find yourself in a fight with Asgore and said fight isn't interrupted at the very start, then you missed something for a Pacifist run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you've already defeated Flowey in a previous run. The flower remembers, and thus gives up without you having to go through Your Best Nightmare.

But if this is your first run, then it might be a glitch caused by a certain scientist.

Comment: So I have to true restart?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to True Restart in order to see the Flowey fight again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that, if you really saw Flowey after he stole Asgore's soul,

> the game crashed, you fought Flowey in his glitched world and then saw the credits.

which is a neutral ending.

After you boot once again the game, Flowey will tell you what you did wrong or what you are missing. Follow his tips.

You might have killed a single mob / boss that you think might be "un-merciable", which sounds like you didn't from the 0 exp, or you might not have completed all of the side quests most likely.

Just listen that little flower ;) he's nothing to be afraid of ;)

Comment: But he didn't ever say anything. He just absorbs the souls, and I get the phone call.

Answer (score 0):

To get the pacifist ending, you have to do the Papyrus date, the Undyne date, the Alphys date and the true lab (in that order). Maintaining LV1 alone won’t give you the pacifist ending. It will only give you the speech from Sans.

Here is how:

1. Return to Snowdin after sparring Papyrus. Ask him to let you in to his house, go into his room, then talk to him.
2. Spare Undyne, give her the water, go to her house (which is to the left of Nastabloc’s house), and speak to Papyrus.
3. Walk between the Core and MTT Resort after sparring Metaton. You should get a call from Undyne. Meet her in Snowdin, and she will ask you to deliver a letter. Do so, and the Alphys date will start.
4. So long as you have not killed any monsters, you will now be able to access a hidden area in the lab.

Answer (score -1):

If you have already defeated Flowey in a previous run without a True Reset, then Flowey will decide it's not worth it. Don't worry, your still on True Pacifist, so just go do whatever is needed to get the ending.